# Java Process and using InputStream and OutputStream

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, processbuilder

I am trying to write an automatic grading program in java for other java programs. My java program uses the ProcessBuilder to create a process (with redirected error output) and then executes the student's java class.

Problem is, I am getting blocked when I try to read from their outputstream.

Now as a test, when I try to run their program alone in the terminal, I try to do all the input at once, but for some reason, I am getting the same blocking behaviour. Their program asks for an integer and then a bunch of strings. If I type the integer and then a space bar followed by the input, the program doesn't work the right way and I get blocked.

Here is the student's program. Assume a Mid object is just an integer and some strings. Try running this program and then for the input actually just type in something like...

```
2 123456 matt smith 2 123455 jim bob 2 4  <- after the 4 hit enter
```

and watch the default "Blocking" behaviour of the program.

```
import java.util.*;
public class HW3
{
    public static Mid createMid()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Mid myMid = new Mid();


        System.out.print("Alpha? ");
        myMid.alpha = in.next();
        System.out.print("First name? ");
        myMid.firstName = in.next();
        System.out.print("Last name? ");
        myMid.lastName = in.next();
        System.out.print("Company? ");
        myMid.company = in.nextInt();


        return myMid;
    }
    public static void printMid(Mid x)
    {
        System.out.println("" + x.alpha + " " + x.lastName + " " + x.firstName + " " + x.company);

        return;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to my HW3");

        System.out.print("How many mids? ");
        int numberMids = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Is this your number..."+numberMids);
    Mid[] arrayMids =  new Mid[numberMids];
        for(int i = 0; i < numberMids; i++)
        {
            arrayMids[i] = createMid();
        }

        System.out.print("What company would you like to print out? ");
        int printCompany = in.nextInt();
        for(int j = 0; j < numberMids; j++)
        {
            if(printCompany == arrayMids[j].company)
            {
                printMid(arrayMids[j]);
            }
        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This program works fine for me when I run it in Eclipse (and create a Mid class). One thing you need to do is print a company you actually entered. If you study the input line you suggested to enter, the companies are all `2` but then you ask to print company `4`.

When I do this, nothing prints out (of course), but the program runs to completion just fine.

When asked to print, if I enter the company I actually entered as input, here is what I see:

```
Welcome to my HW3
How many mids? 2
Is this your number...2
Alpha? 123456
First name? matt
Last name? smith
Company? 2
Alpha? 123455
First name? jim
Last name? bob
Company? 2
What company would you like to print out? 2
123456 smith matt 2
123455 bob jim 2
```

Oh, and make sure to close your Scanner. It's just good programming practice to clean up resources when you're finished using them.

Complete code listing I used to run this in Eclipse (Kepler):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HW3 {

  public static class Mid {
    String alpha;
    String lastName;
    String firstName;
    int company;
  }

  public static Mid createMid() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Mid myMid = new Mid();

    System.out.print("Alpha? ");
    myMid.alpha = in.next();
    System.out.print("First name? ");
        myMid.firstName = in.next();
    System.out.print("Last name? ");
    myMid.lastName = in.next();
    System.out.print("Company? ");
    myMid.company = in.nextInt();

    in.close();

    return myMid;
  }

 public static void printMid(Mid x) {
   System.out.println("" + x.alpha + " " + x.lastName + " " + x.firstName
        + " " + x.company);

    return;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to my HW3");

    System.out.print("How many mids? ");
    int numberMids = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Is this your number..." + numberMids);
    Mid[] arrayMids = new Mid[numberMids];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberMids; i++) {
      arrayMids[i] = createMid();
    }

    System.out.print("What company would you like to print out? ");
    int printCompany = in.nextInt();
    for (int j = 0; j < numberMids; j++) {
      if (printCompany == arrayMids[j].company) {
        printMid(arrayMids[j]);
      }
    }

    in.close();

  }
}
```

HTH

Comment: hmmmm... for some reason I am still getting blocked when I execute it in a standard Ubuntu terminal....

Comment: What version of the JDK are you using? I'm using 1.7. I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and it runs fine from a command line as well.